# How to select child of an ancestor via XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML structure similar to:

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c id="2.3">
      </c>
   </b>
   <d>
      <e>
         <f>
         </f>
      </e>
   </d>
</a>
```

I am inside a template for `"f"` where i want to put a `when` with a test on the first number of `id` of `c`, for instance:

```
<xsl:template match="f">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="substring-before(../../../c/@id, '.') = '2'">
         <xsl:text>Successful</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The above code doesn't works!

Can anyone suggest me a way to make it work?

Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is a `b` between the ancestor and the c.

This should work:

```
substring-before(../../../b/c/@id, '.') = '2'
```

(assuming the second `<b>` was supposed to be a `</b>`)

Answer (score 4):

Relative paths are nice, but sometimes it's useful to be more explicit.

```
<xsl:template match="f">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="substring-before(ancestor::a[1]/b/c/@id, '.') = '2'">
         <xsl:text>Successful</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```